# Como fazer borda sobrescrever um botão?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estou começando a estudar para me tornar front-end, e estou dando os primeiros passos, estou fazendo uma calculadora e dando um estilo pra ela mas não consigo fazer com que o botão 0 fique por tras da bora, alguém pode me ajudar?[image: Calculadora]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ou você adiciona no CSS do botão: border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; ou você dá overflow:hidden na div da calculadora, assim o botão não vai ficar por cima.

Comment: Obrigado amigo ! consegui !

Answer (score 0):

Na  verdade você não precisa colocar a borda atrás de nada, o que é preciso é fazer uma curva na borda inferior-esquerda do botão, para isto precisa utilizar CSS:

Este arredondaria todas as bordas:

```
border-radius: 30px
```

assim tambem arredondaria todas as bordas mas de forma diferente:

```
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
```

Assim que aplica em uma tag:

```
<tag style="border-bottom-left-radius: 30px">...
```

Continue seus estudos.

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo ! consegui !